# count from two tables

Tags: sql, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I've 2 tables, one bats_req which has 96 records and other one is master which has 24341. i need to match **EMP** column in both the tables and print count from bats_req table

count which im getting from below query is incorrect

```
select distinct man , cnt
from ( 

select count(*) cnt, f1.EMP man from bats_req f1
join bats f2
on f1.EMP = f2.EMP
group by f1.EMP
) emp
```

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, you should be doing a left join here, and you should also be counting a column from the table on the right side of the join:

```
SELECT f1.EMP man, COUNT(f2.EMP) cnt
FROM bats_req f1
LEFT JOIN bats f2
    ON f1.EMP = f2.EMP
GROUP BY
    f1.EMP;
```

I don't know what your intention is with the outer subquery, but `EMP` should already be distinct, so that subquery isn't really doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS table1Count FROM table1 WHERE someCondition
JOIN?? 

SELECT COUNT(*) AS table2Count FROM table2 WHERE someCondition
CROSS JOIN? subqueries?

SELECT COUNT(*) AS table3Count FROM table3 WHERE someCondition
```

The goal is to return this:

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| table1Count | table2Count | table3Count |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| 14          | 27          | 0           |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```